# Line Art: A word like Scrimshaw or Filligree?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

I'm looking for a word that refers to a fine, decorative line-work illustration that is used for accenting signage or letterhead. It's similar in usage to scrimshaw (except not a picture) or filigree (except not made of wire).

What word am I looking for?

An example are the decorative lines around and within the Jack Daniels no.7 label, as seen here:
[image: Jack Daniels no.7 Label]!

Comment: While not strictly specific to writing, **ornamentation** and **decoration** both work, no? I do prefer the "flourish" answer, though.

Comment: @mfoy_ In typography terms, "ornament" is a very general term - it can be anything from borders like these to bullets, daggers and leaves. It's very useful when you want to refer to non-letter decoration in a typographic composition but don't know the exact word for the ornament you're looking at.

Comment: (For instance, the little thingers at the left and right edges of the box that contains the phrase "English Language & Usage".)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That type of design is called [Scrollwork](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scrollwork) which originally described the patterns created with a scroll saw but now include graphic designs and even cake decorating.

[image: example of cake decorating using scrollwork from Wikipedia Cake Decorating site]

**Example of simple scrollwork design:**

[image: example of simple scrollwork]

The label you used as an example might have originated as a design carved into wood, as an early means of creating a template that could then be rolled with ink or paint and "stamped" onto paper or cloth, where the etched portions, being below the surface of the piece of wood, would remain white (uninked or painted) on the transferred surface.  This method was known as woodblock printing. Scrollwork was a frequent design element in that art.  This method of printing traces back to the 1500s (on paper) and even earlier on fabric, per this [article](http://www.prepressure.com/printing/history/1400-1499) on the history of printing.

> scrollwork. (n.d.). Collins English Dictionary - Complete & Unabridged 10th Edition. Retrieved June 18, 2015, from Dictionary.com website: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scrollwork

Comment: While it's not the word I thought I was looking for, this is both correct and better for my purposes so I'm calling it the right one! Thanks for the help and for such a well-researched answer!

Answer (score 7):

I think the term you are after is ***[flourish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flourish)***:

> - (Printing, Lithography & Bookbinding) an ornamental embellishment in writing. (Collins Dict.)

[image]